# asp.net Class reference error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

I'm writing a web app in ASP.Net.

At the top of the web page I have:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="software-mgr.aspx.vb" Inherits="ftp_access_software_mgr" EnableViewState="True" EnableSessionState="True" %>
<% 
    Dim ssMgr As SoftwareFTPStorage = New SoftwareFTPStorage
    Dim ssDBMgr As SoftwareStoreDBTools = New SoftwareStoreDBTools
    Dim username As String
    username = getUserName()

    If Not IsPostBack Then buildDBList()

%>
```

On the .aspx.vb page I have:

```
Imports SoftwareFTPStorage
Imports SoftwareStoreDBTools
Imports System
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Partial Class ftp_access_software_mgr
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim ssDBTools As SoftwareStoreDBTools = New SoftwareStoreDBTools
    Dim ssMgrTools As SoftwareFTPStorage = New SoftwareFTPStorage

    Protected Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
        ...Class Code
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RemButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RemButton.Click
        ...Class Code
    End Sub

    Protected Sub buildDBList()
        ...Class Code
    End Sub

    Protected Function getUserName() As String
        ...Class Code
    End Function

End Class
```

I don't know what I did, but at some point *on the server* I started getting the error:

```
    Compilation Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SoftwareStoreDBTools' is not defined.

Source Error:

Line 10:     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Line 11: 
Line 12:     Dim ssDBTools As SoftwareStoreDBTools = New SoftwareStoreDBTools
Line 13:     Dim ssMgrTools As SoftwareFTPStorage = New SoftwareFTPStorage
Line 14:
```

When I debug locally it works great... well, sorta: still working out some "state" issues, but at least I don't get the error page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you deploy the assembly that SoftwareStoreDBTools exists in to your bin directory on the server?

Comment: The only place where SoftwareStoreDBTools is located is in the "App_Code" directory. The reference was working, at one point. And, like I said, it works locally in De-Bug. I'm still knew to asp.net. I'm not sure how or why I'd use a bin directory.

Comment: Place this code on your codebehind file (.aspx.vb) instead and try again: Dim ssMgr As SoftwareFTPStorage = New SoftwareFTPStorage() Dim ssDBMgr As SoftwareStoreDBTools = New SoftwareStoreDBTools() Dim username As String username = getUserName() If Not IsPostBack Then buildDBList()

Comment: in order to do that I had to create a new sub on the aspx.vb and class declaration on the aspx page to point to that sub. All I got was the same error except now it was pointing to the Class instances on the aspx.vb page. Thanks, but this didn't work. Let me stress again, it works when debugging locally, but not on the server. It would seem to me, then, that the problem is not in the code... but I've been wrong before.

Comment: @NoAlias - can you elaberate? It could be that my VS "knew" what to do while my manual deploy did not.

Comment: Your App_Code folder that contains your Classes should be in wwwroot or httpdocs folder once uploaded. Maybe you are putting App_Code inside the ftp_access folder.

Comment: thanks again @CoderRoller. An open brain is what I need to help troubleshoot this thing. I did just confirm that it's going to the right directory at the root... so, no dice.

Comment: Check this and let me know how it goes:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1566777.aspx/1?class+in+App_code+not+defined+
http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-professional/64463-classes-app_code-not-defined.html

Comment: @CoderRoller - I'm not sure how to give you the credit for the answer, but that was it. I had the directory set as an application in IIS and that was hiding the /App_Code directory from the code. Of course, now I have other issues such as the wonderful "Ambiguous" error. Thanks for sticking to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this and let me know how it goes:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1566777.aspx/1?class+in+App_code+not+defined+

http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-professional/64463-classes-app_code-not-defined.html